# $HOME/.cache - on a small SSD or on an HDD?

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage, ssd, directory-structure, home

I have a system with a small SSD (about 90 GB available for my single Linux partition mounted as `/`) and a much larger HDD.

Now, my home directory has been balooning in space, filling up all of the remaining free space on the SSD. Apparently, it's `$HOME/.cache` that's the main culprit - over 33 GB.

Now, what should I do with it?

1. Move it to the HDD and symlink `$HOME/.cache` to `/mnt/my_hdd_partition/some/path/.cache`?
2. Make sure and cull it occasionally?

If you believe I should do the latter, please explain why this would not be too much of a burden.

Comment: I've created a symlink on ramdisk `/dev/shm/`. It's only cache, every content can be easily regenerated.

Comment: @IporSircer: I don't have 33 GB of RAM. Also, I don't want my apps to take that long...

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a few options.

### Move the cache to tmpfs (RAM)

You could choose to mount or symlink it to tmpfs (e.g. anything under `/run` or `/tmp` should be ok on most distros).

Pros:

- Faster cache read/write.
- Automatically wipe the cache on every shutdown (limiting its growth over time).

Cons:

- Cache must be recreated on every initial application/system startup after a fresh boot.
- Cache would potentially use a lot of RAM if you don't reboot for a while.

### Occasionally cull the cache

Occasionally `rm -rf ~/.cache/*` either manually or via an automatic script (e.g. using [`anacron`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron)).

You could even have a script wipe `.cache` only if it exceeds a certain size, maybe run by systemd every shutdown and by anacron every few days.

Pros:

- Still on the SSD so still fairly fast read/write
- Only wiped occasionally, so not every initial startup will require a cache regen.

Cons:

- Either have to manually wipe on occasion or spend time setting up automatic wipes.
- May still fill up the SSD, depending on how fast the cache grows and how often it is wiped.
- Even though less often, you still need to occasionally wipe the cache. This means you will still occasionally have slow initial application startups.

### Move the cache to your HDD

This is probably the most sensible option, it is relatively simple to `rm -rf ~/.cache && ln -s /path/to/new/cache ~/.cache` , but it does have the one disadvantage of potentially slow cache read/writes.

Pros:

- Simple
- No need to wipe the cache
- Application startups should never need to fully regen the cache
- Not going to use up RAM or SSD space

Cons:

- Potentially slower read/write to cache. It is debatable if this will be noticeable.

### Get a bigger SSD

Ok, so this may not be a valid option, but it's worth mentioning. SSD's are still expensive, but they are getting cheaper all the time.

If you bought your 90GB SSD a few years ago it is likely that you would be able to more than double the size by spending the same again.

Pros

- You would have a bigger SSD, meaning cache may no longer take up a significant portion of it.

Cons:

- New PC hardware is expensive!

### Conclusion

While there are a few options and each has its pros and cons, each of them are relatively simple to implement and de-implement, so there is no reason why you shouldn't try one option and then later test out an alternative.

Personally, I would the cache onto the HDD (that's what the hard drive is for!) and consider sticking a bigger SSD on my wishlist, in the hope that one day I have the spare cash.